# Selecting rows where value don't exist in other table

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I've got two tables. One for main accounts and one for banned accounts and I wanna select all the members in the main accounts and only those who is not banned.

```
SELECT Username, $field AS Output
FROM `Player_Accounts`, `Ban_List`
WHERE Ban_List.Banned_Name != Username
ORDER BY $field DESC LIMIT 0, 25;
```

The query take over 1,30min to execute and display the results

Comment: I am assuming you are using `mysql_*`, so I will tell you that there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: In addition to whatever queries you see down below, do make sure both Banned_Name and Username are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your query is not right. The number of rows are very high (have you 1.3 million of users???)

Try this:

```
SELECT p.username
FROM Player_Accounts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'BANNED'
    FROM Ban_List b
    WHERE b.banned_name = p.username
)
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT p.username
FROM Player_Accounts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ban_List b
ON p.username = b.banned_name
WHERE b.banned_name IS NULL
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN is not an alternative but the only solution (at least for mysql).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

SELECT p.Username, p.Pocket_Money
FROM Player_Accounts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ban_List b
ON p.Username = b.Banned_Name
WHERE b.Banned_Name IS NULL
ORDER BY p.Pocket_Money DESC LIMIT 0, 25;

Showing rows 0 - 24 ( 25 total, Query took 103.6118 sec)


Ban_List = 1,583 rows total
Player_Accounts = 6,154 total